# Laptop loses wireless VNC connection

Tags: wireless-networking, vnc, wireless-router, port-forwarding

I'm using VNC server to connect through my wireless router to my laptop and PC.

I set a static IP to the both machines and added two virtual services to the wireless router, which is a [D-LINK](http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=226).

There is no problem with the VNC and the PC, but the laptop loses connection and something is not right. Can someone tell me why?

Windows 7
VNC 2.0.4

Comment: Umm can you add any details? OS? VNC software? I assume the desktop works fine, but you don't state explicitly that it does.... I could go on for a while... Your first step would be to provide enough info to narrow it down to either the router or the Laptop. A brief example would be to plug the laptop in with a ethernet cord and see if the problem still happens. Also does the Laptop fully lose connection when this happens? Try running a continuous ping that way when you get connection back you can check the pings to see if any traffic was passing during the outage.

Comment: *> the laptop loses connection and something is not right*, this is where you need to tell us more. Does it always lose connection, or just when you VNC to the machine? Can you otherwise browse normally, for example?

Comment: OS - Windows 7
VNC - 2.0.4
I fixed the connection but now I can't connect to the laptop through some other computer using VNC Viewer.

Comment: How did you fix the connection? How exactly can you not connect? Can you ping the machine? You need to give us more details to work with, otherwise we can't possibly help you.

Comment: I use the validate on exit in the properties window of the Ipv4. Then window 7 just fixed it. But the problem is that I can't access the laptop through vnc. yes I can ping the machine. Maybe the problem for the conection is that I use on the same laptop machine vpn connection which is not active.

Comment: For the testing the connection I use another laptop with different IP address and I can connect to the PC but notto my laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure both computers are in the same network and behind the same NAT, but probably they are, because they can ping each other. Also make sure you have the VNC Server running on the machine you want to connect to. Then make sure you have no firewall blocking your VNC connection on the machine you want to access.

Comment: Opps the firewall was the problem. I have two firewalls on windows and on the antivirus program. Thanks

Comment: Disable one of the firewalls. You should only have or need one firewall on your computer at any given time.